# WPF удалить подсветку курсора в ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Работаю с WPF 4.0. Требуется просто вывести на экран список чего-либо без выбора, но с прокруткой при необходимости. Лучше всего на мой взгляд подходить ListBox. Написал следующий шаблон для ListBoxItem

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NoSelectedItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Вроде все должно работать по логике, нашел много аналогичных примеров в Инете. Но при наводке курсора на Item в ListBox'е, он все равно подсвечивается голубым светом. Пробовал изменить другие свойства в триггере

```
 <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
 </Trigger>
```

Все меняется, кроме цвета "прямоугольника" подсветки, он все время остается голубым. Border в последнем случае меняет толщину, но цвет тоже остается голубым, только чуть темнее. Такое впечатление, что сверху накладывается какой-то прямоугольник голубого цвета.
Как можно избавиться от этой голубой подсветки? 
Работаю в настольном приложении, но в Windows 10

Comment: Для простого отображения коллекции (без подсветки и проч.) лучше всего подходит `<ItemsControl>`

Comment: Это я знаю, но хотелось бы попробовать решить с ListBox

Comment: Заверните `ItemsControl` в `ScrollViewer` и используйте без костылей. Будет и прокрутка, и отсутствие возможности выбора.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сам дошел до этого, все прекрасно работает